# data-href not working with Facebook Share in Angular

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am trying to share a post to Facebook and Twitter on angular

here is what I am building
http://kensproblems.com/#/posts/My-Revision-History-Is-Not-Showing-Up-on-Wordpress-Posts-

I figured out the twitter one like below

```
<a class="btn btn-success twitter" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fkensproblems.com%2F%23%2Fposts%2F{{post.url}}&hashtags=kensproblems&text={{post.title}}&via=manchasdemiel"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> tweet</a>
```

Not sure why the facebook one doesn't work. I tried the 2 different ways below:
The first one works but doesn't grab my whole post. The second one doesn't open at all. is it the hashtag?

```
<a class="btn btn-success facebook" href="#" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://kensproblems.com" onclick="window.open(this.dataset.href, 'facebook-share', 'width=550,height=235');return false;"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> share</a>

<a class="btn btn-success facebook" href="#" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=httpw://blog.kenmau.com/#/posts/10-Ways-To-Get-Out-Of-Bed-Faster" onclick="window.open(this.dataset.href, 'facebook-share', 'width=550,height=235');return false;"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> share</a>
```

Any help is appreciated!

thank you!